# Nuget fails to install all packages

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

For example, if I try to include moment.js in my project through the package manager, this occurs:

```
Installing 'Moment.js 2.7.0'.
Successfully installed 'Moment.js 2.7.0'.
Adding 'Moment.js 2.7.0' to ServiceSite.
Uninstalling 'Moment.js 2.7.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Moment.js 2.7.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

I'm not sure why it starts uninstalling moment.js after it was installed successfully. This same sequence of events happens for any package I try to install or update. This is a local issue to my machine, and is likely due to VS 2010.

I have tried uninstalling and then installing nuget itself and it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The message sequence was a little out of sync, but basically it says installed failed. It could be visual studio going into a bad state.

Try a devenv.exe /setup on the machine from an admin command prompt. That may fix the VS weirdness.